# Fast Report Page Navigation issue

Tags: delphi, vbscript, fastreport

The report generates the result first for page1(Summary) and Details after that.
the report result generated all the rows from Page1(Summary) first like records 1,2,...n and then from page2(Details) reconds 1,2,....n

I would like to print from page1(Summary) for records 1 and then record 1 from (Detail) page (which is InvoiceNo_1_Summary and then InvoiceNo1_Detail) rather than all records from Summary page first and then Details

The report has come through with all the Summary first and then the details have come through at the end of the report.
I need fix so details for same record Summary and Details come through with the Summary followed by the correct Statement.

Fast Report
Two pages for (pgSummary) the source from query1 and 
            page (pgDetails) from query2

I need fix so details for same record Summary and Details come through with the Summary followed by the correct Statement for same invoice i.e. InvoiceNo1.

Answer (score 1):

you need parameter to display same record on Detail table same as Master table record number, here example with ADOQuery with SQL Server

1. ADOQueryMaster

   select * from invoice where date='1/1/2019'
2. ADOQueryDetail

   select * from detinvoice where InvNo=:InvNo

in ADOQueryDetail Properties:

- set Master=AdoQueryMaster
- set Params for paramters data type above

Then Insert Band into Report Page

1. MasterData, dataset= ADOQueryMaster
2. DetailData, dataset = ADOQueryDetail

Comment: Thanks ,I have manage to format my report using Group Header /Footer